# Async Validator is not registering errors in Angular Material AutoComplete

Tags: angular, asynchronous, angular-material

I have a form control that must verify that a code exists so I created an async Validator function:

```js
//this function seems to function correctly
codeExists(): AsyncValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): Observable<ValidationErrors | null> =>
      this.codes.pipe(
        map((codes) =>
          codes.find((val) => control.value === val)
            ? null
            : { error: 'afsender bestaan nie' }
        )
      );
  }
```

with corresponding form control

```js
codeControl = new FormControl('', [Validators.required], [this.codeExists()]);
```

with template

```html
<mat-form-field appearance="fill" id="kode" floatLabel="always">
  <input
    matInput
    [formControl]="codeControl"
  />
  <mat-error *ngIf="codeControl.invalid">
    {{ codeControl.errors?.error }}
  </mat-error>
  ...
</mat-form-field>
```

I confirmed that the validator function is called every time the input value changes and the function returns an error when it should, but the code control does not register the error. `codeControl.invalid` stays false and `codeControl.errors` is undefined. I have tested a Synchronous version of the validator that works fine.

Comment: see working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rjtkqu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

maybe try to debug the response given in the observable and see what you get in the response

Comment: The response by the observable is correct as expected but the FormControl does not register when an error is returned.

Comment: Is your observable complete after emitting value?

Answer (score 1):

Use custom validator for autocomplete.

```
//Validate Options from Array of strings
autocompleteStringValidator(validOptions: Array<string>): ValidatorFn {
return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } | null => {
if (validOptions.indexOf(control.value) !== -1) {
  return null  /* valid option selected */
}
return { 'invalidAutocompleteString': { value: control.value } }
 }
}

//Validate Options from Array of Objects
autocompleteObjectValidator(): ValidatorFn {
return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } | null => {
  if (typeof control.value === 'string') {
    return { 'invalidAutocompleteObject': { value: control.value } }
  }
  return null  /* valid option selected */
  }
}
```

And use like this

```
codeControl = new FormControl('', { validators: [autocompleteObjectValidator(), Validators.required] });
```